# GestureDetector inside PageView not working on first Page

Tags: dart, flutter

If Page2 is selected the `GestureDetector` works fine when tapping on Page1/Page3. Same goes for Page3 and tapping on Page2/Page4. Also Page4 and tapping on Page3 is working fine, but as soon as Page1 is selected the tap on Page2 won't work at all. Where is my mistake or is this just a bug?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home:MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({this.title});
  final String title;

  _createBox(String title, Color color) {
    return Center(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => print("Tapped on $title."),
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          color: color,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(title),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: PageView(
            controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.7),
            children: <Widget>[
              _createBox("Box 1", Colors.green),
              _createBox("Box 2", Colors.blue),
              _createBox("Box 3", Colors.green),
              _createBox("Box 4", Colors.blue),
              _createBox("Box 5", Colors.green),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Screenrecord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TT86J.gif)

Comment: what exactly is not working?  you don't see a console output of "Tapped on Box 1"?

Comment: As you can see in the Screenrecord the console output of "Tapped on Box 2" is missing when tapping on the fraction of Page2 while Page1 is 100% visible.

Comment: Have you figured out this? I'm having the same issue as well